# Chrome: The same version, the different CSS styles on the same page

Tags: css

I have a strange problem. Both me and my client have the same version of the Chrome browser: 20.0.1132.57 m. The problem is, I get a feedback from my client about bad css layout on some pages (everything is smashed, all css styles are not applied). The problem is, when I enter that pages everything is fine. What may cause that problem ? I have no clue where to start digging

Comment: Does the client have a cached version of the stylesheet? do you?

Comment: Perhaps he is not loading the CSS file at all?

Comment: if they dont have some fonts on their system that you used that could lead to some pixels being off here and there when the browser substitutes

Comment: Could the chrome Window size be changing the flow and size of elements?

Comment: @Tim Medora, I think he is, but I recommended him to refresh the page by CTRL + F5. Still the same result

Comment: @Calvin Jia, It looks like You say, but why I see all the styles are correctly loaded and he's not?

Comment: Could he have plugins/addons installed that alter appearance? Can you compare configuration of your Chromes?

Comment: @John B, in every page it is being used the same font, in that case (as You say) on every page he shouldn't see the CSS, but the problem is only on the two pages

Comment: @Trekstuff, it can be some trail, how we can compare the configurations ?

Comment: @Tony: Try looking at chrome://chrome/extensions/

Comment: @Trekstuff I did, and also I'm waiting now for some info about my client's browser config

Comment: Have you tried forcing the browser to use the latest stylesheet by adding a query string (style.css?v=1.0) to the link?

Comment: @Tony well if its only 2 pages, I would go through the elements on that page and check to see if theres a weird font used there or even a giant image file or something thats delaying other stuff from loading on theirs but is cached on yours.

Comment: @John B, the only thing that can do some mess is a flash object (ISSUU document viewer)

Answer (score 1):

**Cache deleting** and refreshing the site with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (force refresh) should solve the problem at your client.